# Error in sessionMessages.add() method when migrated from liferay 6.2 to liferay DXP

Tags: liferay-7

This is my current code in liferay 6.2.

`SessionMessages.add(actionRequest.getPortletSession(),
                 "User-Approved");`

The sessionmessages.add() method no longer can take portlet session as arg.Then how i change the argument in liferay 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replace your code with:

```
SessionMessages.add(actionRequest,"User-Approved");
```

because **javax.portlet.ActionRequest** extends **javax.portlet.PortletRequest** interface and there is a SessionMessages.add method with that parameter type:

```
public static void add(PortletRequest portletRequest, String key) {
        Map<String, Object> map = _getMap(portletRequest, true);

        if (map == null) {
            return;
        }

        map.put(key, key);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks .Do SessionMessages.add(actionRequest,"User-Approved"); and  SessionMessages.add(PortalUtil.getHttpServletRequest(actionRequest),"User-Approved")  have the same effect?

Comment: Hi @srigin that doesn't have the same effect. First one add the information at portlet session level and second one adds the information at portal session level. (each portlet has its own session)

Comment: Thanks.I was really helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can still pass the whole request object.

`public static void add(PortletRequest portletRequest, String key)`

Comment: Thanks.But i dont have the PortletRequest  object with me